# Qual a melhor ferramenta free e online em alternativa ao Jira?

Tags: gerenciamento-de-projetos

O [jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira) é uma ótima ferramenta para acompanhar bugs e histórias, porém é paga.

Alguém conhece uma ferramenta compatível free e online?

Comment: Eu concordo que seria legal ter um plano gratuito, mas [10 dólares ao mês para uma equipe de 10 pessoas](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/pricing) com toda a infra pronta na nuvem acaba sendo muito mais barato que manter um sistema "em casa", pois sem contar o hardware e a energia, o tempo investindo em manutenção e segurança podem passar em muitas vezes o custo de um SaaS online. **Aviso: eu trabalho na Atlassian**, mas considere que esse conceito de terceirização na nuvem é universalmente reconhecido.

Comment: Já trabalhei com diversas ferramentas mas como o Jira não vi nenhuma ainda. O que implementei onde trabalho é o uso de http://www.redmine.org/ + https://getbrimir.com/ + Trello. O Redmine e o Brimir são para Ruby on Rails e roda em um servidor interno. Já o Trello é via Internet mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para quem utiliza o repositório Bitbucket, eles disponibilizam um sistema para controle de incidentes, gratuito, bem simples e privativo.
Uma ótima opção.

Answer (score 2):

Já trabalhei em alguns projetos utilizando o [Trello](https://trello.com/).

Se você não estiver procurando por algo tão rebuscado quanto o jira, é uma opção a se considerar.

Outra ferramenta que eu já pude utilizar foi o [Mantis](https://www.mantisbt.org/), porém, apenas utilizei em uma empresa que trabalhei. Não sei como é feita a configuração dele.

Comment: O Trello possui a camada *free*, mas também [opções de *upgrade*](https://trello.com/pricing) para empresas ou uso mais complexo da ferramenta.

Comment: Correto, @utluiz, mas como ele procura por algo free, acabei não caindo nessa questão por achar desnecessário para a pergunta. Enfim, essa nossa discussão acaba enriquecendo a pergunta. ;)

Comment: Perfeito, foi só para complementar. A opção de *upgrade* é até uma vantagem, pois permite investir depois que a ferramenta já está em uso.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, atualmente uso o Trello. Agora estou buscando uma ferramenta para controlar melhor as demandas.

Answer (score 0):

Tennho usado o [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) nos meus projetos com equipes de mais de 15 usuários, e ele atende muito bem aos meus requisitos, come:

- Issue tracking, identificando o que é bug, melhoria ou nova funcionalidade
- Suporte a versões do sistema
- Suporte a sub projetos, quando você divide o sistema em módulos
- Documentação do sistema e Wikis
- Roadmaps
- Integração com seu repositório de código fonte
- Sistema de plugin para expandir com novos recursos

Recomendo

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia - Confesso que conheco uma ferramenta,mas infelizmente o periodo gratuito nao esta disponivel para sempre.. http://kanbantool.com -alem disso, penso que Kanban oferece muitas oportunidades e organiza bastante a sua vida professional. Recomendo tentar arranjar a sua rotina diaria com Kanban para ver efazer uma diferenca :) Um abraco muito grande para todos Voces :)